# Use Mechanize to retrieve ALL links of a website

Tags: ruby, recursion, mechanize, web-crawler

How can I use the `Mechanize` library to find all the links on a website?

I'de like to parse the internal links recursively in order to grab all the links of a website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you looked at the [Anemone](http://anemone.rubyforge.org/) gem? It was specifically created for spidering websites.

You could do something like this to grab and print all the links of a website:

```
require 'anemone'

Anemone.crawl("http://www.example.com/") do |anemone|
  anemone.focus_crawl { |page| puts page.links }
end
```

It is fairly well documented with options to select if you want to spider the entire side, exclude certain types of links, or exclude links that are like something.

Answer (score 0):

Not a ruby solution but I find [this script](https://github.com/adamdehaven/fetchurls) simple and effective.